# Intertwine two lists

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I merge two lists that are equal length, creating a list of intertwined elements?

For example, lists `2, 4, 6` and `1, 3, 5` should produce `2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5` in racket.

I am having a difficult time figuring this out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? post your code! Stack Overflow is not a place to get your homework done for free

Comment: (define (interwine list1 list2)
  (if [(empty? list1) empty]
      (cons first list1
            (interwine ???
                   
(check-expect(interleave '(2 4 6) '(1 3 5)) '(2 1 4 3 6 5))

Comment: this is not homework, just learning scheme on my own.

Comment: you almost got it! read my commented code below to get the last line right. And well, if it's not homework, anyway it's better if you solve this on your own, you'll learn a lot more this way ;)

Comment: (define (interwine list1 list2)
  (if [(empty? list1) empty]
      (cons first list1
            (interwine (first list2)
                       (rest list1)))))
                   
(check-expect(interleave '(2 4 6) '(1 3 5)) '(2 1 4 3 6 5))

Comment: There are parenthesis problems in that code. Some parenthesis are missing, some are unnecessary. And the recursive call is wrong, read again the comments in my answer. Test it, test it again, you'll reach the answer.

Comment: (define (interleave list1 list2)
      (if (empty? list1) list2
      (if (empty? list2) list1
       (cons (first list1)
            (interleave (first list2)
                        (rest list1))))))


;(check-expect(interleave '(2 4 6) '(1 3 5)) '(2 1 4 3 6 5))
;(check-expect(interleave '(10 9) '(1 3)) '(10 1 9 3))

Comment: The last `(first list2)` is wrong, it's just `list2`. And there's no need to use a nested `if`, see my answer, there's only one `if` there

Answer (score 1):

The general approach for this sort of problem is to solve the problem for the first element(s) and then recurse for the rest.  If you solve this problem:

```
(zip '(2) '(1))
```

then the recursion looks like so (with the termination conditions expressed first):

```
(define (zip list1 list2)
  (cond ((null? list1) list2)
        ((null? list2) list1)
        (else (cons (car list1)
                    (cons (car list2)
                          (zip (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))))))

> (zip '(a b c) '(1))
(a 1 b c)
> (zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
(a 1 b 2 c 3)
> (zip '(a) '(1 2 3))
(a 1 2 3)
```

Notice the two `null?` clauses.  This allows `list1` or `list2` to be a different size; whatever is left over gets appended to the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to learn the *batteries included* aspect of Racket:

```
#lang racket
(define (intertwine L1 L2)
  (flatten (map cons L1 L2)))
```

Quick test.

```
> (intertwine '(2 4 6) '(1 3 5))
'(2 1 4 3 6 5)
```

**NOTE** works in the case of equal sized lists, per question posed. Will not handle differences in length as @GoZoner's answer will.

Re-implementing functions is a good way to practice programming in the small. Learning the library will allow for greater productivity and cleaner code. IMHO